# hide and unhide context strip menu item c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

```
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            string signatureDate = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            // MessageBox.Show(signatureDate);
            if(signatureDate.Length > 5)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[0].Visible = false;
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[1].Visible = true;
            }else
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[0].Visible = true;
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[1].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

I have a context strip menu that is working in my datagridview. And I selected it as Row Context Strip Menu.

What I am trying to do is to get if selected row of datagridview and control signature column is null or not. If it has signature date I want to hide or unhide "Sign" and if it doesn't have signature date hide "Unsign" item on context menu strip.

You can see in picture I enclosed.[Context menu Strip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KabS.png)

EDIT: Name of the event is MouseDown.
EDIT 2: With editing this code I can get columns data and show them on messageBox. But I can not use those data as a condition. Therefore it is not working. For example, when I select a row that is without "Signature Date" and show it on messageBox, it is working. But when I use Signature Date data as a condition It is not working. I know it is so strange and too easy to overcome but I coundn't because of that I didn't catch anything.

EDIT 3: [Event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQaKI.png)

**EDIT 4 (SOLVED) :** I created to Context Strip Menu and specify no one of them
as Context strip Menu of Datagridview.

With Datagridview_MouseDown event, I am getting Signature Date column data and check if it is null/empty or not. If it is null/empty I specify first Context Menu strip as Context Strip Menu of Datagridview or not I do revise. I figured out the solution in this way :)

Comment: The code looks good. Just place some break points and see if it's running or not.

Comment: What is the name of the event firing this function ?
Make sure it's MouseDown

Comment: @Emad, thanks for your answer, I put some break points it looks good but it doesn't work.

Comment: @CodeJoy Name of event is MouseDown.

Comment: @JohnG, I know that it is a simple action that hiding and unhiding any of them. But It doesn't work. I didn't catch anything.

Comment: Have you tried the DataGridView's ContextMenuStrip property?

Comment: @JohnG, If you mean specify it as DataGridView ContextStripMenu, yes I have tried.

Comment: I really haven't a clue, both answers should work.. I tried them. I would show your COMPLETE event as 'if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)' doesn't exactly show which event you started with.

Comment: @JohnG I have just added a picture that show my event code. You can check it out. And thank you for your effort in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is in the instance of context menu strip use this one see if it helps.

```
if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            string signatureDate = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            // MessageBox.Show(signatureDate);
            if(signatureDate.Length > 5)
            {
                dataGridView3.ContextMenu.Items[0].Visible = false;
                dataGridView3.ContextMenu.Items[1].Visible = true;
            }else
            {
                dataGridView3.ContextMenu.Items[0].Visible = true;
                dataGridView3.ContextMenu.Items[1].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your event is not firing.
Instead of using mouse down you could also use the Opening event of the contextMenuStrip

This should solve your problem

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView3.ContextMenu = contextMenuStrip1;
            contextMenuStrip1.Opening += contextMenuStrip1_Opening;
        }


private void contextMenuStrip1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            string signatureDate = dataGridView3.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            // MessageBox.Show(signatureDate);
            if (signatureDate.Length > 5)
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[0].Visible = false;
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[1].Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[0].Visible = true;
                contextMenuStrip1.Items[1].Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: No, It didn't work. I tried yours and Datagridview_Mouse down in your way. Both of them did'nt work.